# Stellar catalogues stars in specific sky regions – without downloading the catalogs

Tags: sky-survey, star-catalogues

I’m interested, to give a scientific realism to a project I’m working on, in finding a picture of all stars belonging to a star catalogue such as Tycho 2 or Hipparcos for some very specific sky regions.

Since I have little time available, I’m wondering whether there’s a quicker way (maybe online?) than downloading the whole catalog and browsing through it via some dedicated software.

Thank you

D.

Comment: Do you mean something like http://skyview.gsfc.nasa.gov/current/cgi/titlepage.pl

Comment: @barrycarter - that's look great! I guess it suits my purposes. Thanks a lot